# SQL Server : Variables Drop Tables and Schema

Tags: sql-server, variables

I am attempting to perform a drop table using variables and other variables within other variables. Some of the variables are defined by queries then used in results of other queries. I however am having an issue with this as when I parse I get

> Command(s) completed successfully.

However when I attempt to execute I get the following error message.

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'S' to data type int.

I can't figure out what actually has the value of 'S'.

Line 18 refers to

```
EXEC @defn_id_query
```

The variable which it is referring to is the listed below

```
SET @defn_id_query = (
'SELECT defn_id FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[defn]
WHERE [defn_type_name] = ''CONTAINER''
AND defn_subtype_id = 1
AND defn_name = ''' + @schema + ''
)
```

Below is the full code

```
DECLARE @defn_ver_id_query varchar
DECLARE @defn_ver_id int
DECLARE @defn_id_query varchar
DECLARE @defn_id int
DECLARE @schema varchar
DECLARE @deleteschema varchar
DECLARE @systemschema varchar
DECLARE @variableSET varchar
DECLARE @deletesreferences varchar
SET @schema = 'fpscdb001_ws_001'
SET @systemschema = '[fpscdb001_system]'
SET @defn_id_query = (
'SELECT defn_id FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[defn]
WHERE [defn_type_name] = ''CONTAINER''
AND defn_subtype_id = 1
AND defn_name = ''' + @schema + ''
)
EXEC @defn_id_query
EXEC @defn_ver_id_query
SET @defn_id = (@defn_id_query)
SET @defn_ver_id = (@defn_ver_id_query)
SET @defn_ver_id_query = ('SELECT [defn_ver_id]
  FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[defn_ver]
  WHERE defn_id = @defn_id')
SET @deleteschema = (
'DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[id_generator]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_bal]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_event_sum]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_HOURS]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE1]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE2]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE3]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE3a]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE3b]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE3c]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE3d]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_Stage4]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_ST_STAGE1]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_ST_STAGE2]DECLARE @defn_ver_id_query varchar
DECLARE @defn_ver_id int
DECLARE @defn_id_query varchar
DECLARE @defn_id int
DECLARE @schema varchar
DECLARE @deleteschema varchar
DECLARE @systemschema varchar
DECLARE @variableSET varchar
DECLARE @deletesreferences varchar
SET @schema = 'fpscdb001_ws_001'
SET @systemschema = '[fpscdb001_system]'
SET @defn_id_query = (
'SELECT defn_id FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[defn]
WHERE [defn_type_name] = ''CONTAINER''
AND defn_subtype_id = 1
AND defn_name = ''' + @schema + ''
)
SET @defn_id = (@defn_id_query)
SET @defn_ver_id = (@defn_ver_id_query)
EXEC @defn_id_query
EXEC @defn_ver_id_query

SET @defn_ver_id_query = ('SELECT [defn_ver_id]
  FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[defn_ver]
  WHERE defn_id = @defn_id')
SET @deleteschema = (
'DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[id_generator]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_bal]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_event_sum]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_HOURS]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE1]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE2]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE3]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE3a]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE3b]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE3c]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE3d]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_Stage4]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_ST_STAGE1]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_ST_STAGE2]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_ST_STAGE3]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_status]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_transn]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_transn_sum]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[item_field_journal]
DROP SCHEMA ' + @schema
)
SET @deletesreferences = ('
DELETE FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[defn_reln]
 WHERE from_defn_ver_id = @defn_ver_id
DELETE FROM  ' + @systemschema + '.[defn_ver]
WHERE defn_id = ' + @defn_id + '
DELETE FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[cal_wksp]
WHERE wksp_defn_id = ' + @defn_id + '
DELETE FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[bus_proc_defn]
WHERE defn_id = ' + @defn_id + '
DELETE FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[defn]
WHERE [defn_type_name] = ''CONTAINER''
AND defn_subtype_id = 1
and defn_id = ' + @defn_id)
EXEC @deleteschema
EXEC @deletesreferences

DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_ST_STAGE3]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_status]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_transn]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_transn_sum]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[item_field_journal]
DROP SCHEMA ' + @schema
)
SET @deletesreferences = ('
DELETE FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[defn_reln]
 WHERE from_defn_ver_id = @defn_ver_id
DELETE FROM  ' + @systemschema + '.[defn_ver]
WHERE defn_id = ' + @defn_id + '
DELETE FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[cal_wksp]
WHERE wksp_defn_id = ' + @defn_id + '
DELETE FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[bus_proc_defn]
WHERE defn_id = ' + @defn_id + '
DELETE FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[defn]
WHERE [defn_type_name] = ''CONTAINER''
AND defn_subtype_id = 1
and defn_id = ' + @defn_id)
EXEC @deleteschema
EXEC @deletesreferences
```

I am open to other solutions what do the professionals suggest?

Thanks

EDIT:

I'm guessing the cancelling of all of these apostrophes is confusing me... I have tried the following

```
SET @defn_ver_id_query = ('SELECT [defn_ver_id]
FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[defn_ver]
WHERE defn_id = convert(nvarchar(max),' + @defn_id + '')
```

I have also tried this way as well.

```
SET @defn_ver_id_query = ('SELECT [defn_ver_id]
FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[defn_ver]
WHERE defn_id = ' + convert(nvarchar(max),@defn_id) + '')
```

New FULL edit

```
DECLARE @defn_ver_id_query varchar(max)
DECLARE @defn_ver_id int
DECLARE @defn_id_query varchar(max)
DECLARE @defn_id int
DECLARE @schema varchar(max)
DECLARE @deleteschema varchar(max)
DECLARE @systemschema varchar(max)
DECLARE @variableSET varchar(max)
DECLARE @deletesreferences varchar(max)
SET @schema = 'fpscdb001_ws_001'
SET @systemschema = '[fpscdb001_system]'
SET @defn_id_query = (
'SELECT defn_id FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[defn]
WHERE [defn_type_name] = ''CONTAINER''
AND defn_subtype_id = 1
AND defn_name = ' + @schema + ''
)
SET @defn_id = (@defn_id_query)
SET @defn_ver_id = (@defn_ver_id_query)
EXEC (@defn_id_query)
EXEC (@defn_ver_id_query)

SET @defn_ver_id_query = ('SELECT [defn_ver_id]
  FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[defn_ver]
  WHERE defn_id = ' + convert(nvarchar(max),@defn_id) + '')
SET @deleteschema = (
'DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[id_generator]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_bal]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_event_sum]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_HOURS]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE1]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE2]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE3]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE3a]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE3b]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE3c]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_STAGE3d]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_FH_Stage4]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_ST_STAGE1]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_ST_STAGE2]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_ST_STAGE3]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_status]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_transn]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[incident_transn_sum]
DROP TABLE ' + @schema + '.[item_field_journal]
DROP SCHEMA ' + @schema
)
SET @deletesreferences = ('
DELETE FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[defn_reln]
 WHERE from_defn_ver_id = ' + convert(nvarchar(max),@defn_ver_id) + '
DELETE FROM  ' + @systemschema + '.[defn_ver]
WHERE defn_id = ' + convert(nvarchar(max),@defn_id) + '
DELETE FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[cal_wksp]
WHERE wksp_defn_id = ' + convert(nvarchar(max),@defn_id) + '
DELETE FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[bus_proc_defn]
WHERE defn_id = ' + convert(nvarchar(max),@defn_id) + ' 
DELETE FROM ' + @systemschema + '.[defn]
WHERE [defn_type_name] = ''CONTAINER''
AND defn_subtype_id = 1
and defn_id = ' + convert(nvarchar(max),@defn_id))
EXEC (@deleteschema)
EXEC (@deletesreferences)
```

Comment: Declaring `varchar` without length is part of your problem. Also you need to cast int to `varchar` when concatenating using `+`. And need brackets in the `exec` calls.

Comment: If you declare `varchar` without a length, it defaults to `varchar(1)`.  So, for example, your variable `@defn_ver_id_query` = 'S'.  Plus everything else the other folks have pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Okay now I have made the adjustments you and lonic have made now I am getting an error message I believe I am miss using the "SET".  I am hoping to SET defn_id to the results of defn_id_query.

Comment: After doing some looking up on this I believe I am supposed to be using "sp_executesql", still trying to find an example that will be close to what I am using.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

1. If you try to concat a value to a string that isn't a string, convert it! Example: `SET @string = 'Hello '+CONVERT(nvarchar(max),1);`
2. If you convert a value to `NVARCHAR` you need to specify a length. Example: `NVARCHAR(100)`. In your case, as you try to concat it to a SQL Query, you just can use `CONVERT(nvarchar(max),...)`. It will fallback to the lower length afterwards.
3. You try to use Strings inside Strings. Example: `SET @string = 'The String holds 'User'!'`. This is wrong. You need to escape commas in your String, you can do this by doube quoting. See this example: `SET @string = 'The String holds ''User''!'`
4. If you try to add a value to a string, you need to add + between it: `SET @string = 'Hello ' + 'User';`
5. If you try to execute dynamic SQL (which you tried), you need to evaluate the SQL variable. You do this by using braces around the string. Example: `EXEC(@sqlString)`. You try to do it that way: `EXEC @sqlString`. This ways SQL Server looks for a Procedure called @sqlString, which is wrong.

Hopefully this will help you to fix all your issues.

Comment: @lonic I have made some adjustments per your suggestions, I tried adjusting per your first suggestion which I have added them to my edit section, I believe I got my apostrophes corrected now as well and I added the () around each of my exec as well.

Comment: Yes it looks quite better now! On the first sight, I think it should work now?

Comment: Ah well, one thing I've seen at your code.
`SET @defn_ver_id_query = ('SELECT [defn_ver_id] ...)` those brackets aren't needed for a string assignment. You need the brackets for the `EXEC` later on, but not for the assignment. You can leave them out there.